# Firebase permission denied right after $createUser

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Inside my web-app, Firebase always tells me permission denied while things are working fine in the simulator.

```
FIREBASE WARNING: set at /users/simplelogin:14 failed: permission_denied
```

I'm having trouble adding metadata (such as a name) when users register. `data` is simply a JSON object that contains a `name` property.

```
var signup = function (email, password, data) {
    firebaseAuth
        .$createUser(email, password)
        .then(function (user) {
            dataRef.child('users').child(user.uid)
            .set(data);
        }, function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
};
```

My firebase rules:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users": {
          "$user": {            
            ".read": "$user == auth.uid",
            ".write": "$user == auth.uid"
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Simulator works fine:

```
Attempt to write {"name":"Test"} to /users/simplelogin:7 with auth={"uid":"simplelogin:7"}
    /
    /users
    /users/simplelogin:7:.write: "$user == auth.uid"
        => true

Write was allowed.
```

Comment: You haven't authenticated. Creating a user does not log them in.

Comment: @Kato I'm having the same issue, but I am authenticating. Any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 2):

As @Kato pointed out you need to log the user in yourself after registration before you can do anything.

[Firebase createUser docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/simplelogin/createuser.html)